# Using Conditional XPath in Mule ESB

Tags: xpath, mule, esb

My input XML is

```
<DatabaseValues>
<Value>
    <Sender>Satya</Sender>
    <WB_TRANSFORMATION>1</WB_TRANSFORMATION>
    <WB_VALIDATION>0</WB_VALIDATION>
    <WB_ENRICHMENT>0</WB_ENRICHMENT>
    <Receiver>Ch</Receiver>
</Value>
<Value>
    <Sender>Keerthika</Sender>
    <WB_TRANSFORMATION>1</WB_TRANSFORMATION>
    <WB_VALIDATION>0</WB_VALIDATION>
    <WB_ENRICHMENT>0</WB_ENRICHMENT>
    <Receiver>SS</Receiver>
</Value>
```

My requirement is to extract the `<Receiver>` value based on the corresponding `<Sender>` value. (eg. I need to extract "Ch" when Sender value is "Satya"). This should be achieved using an xpath expression.

I have tried the following

```
<set-variable variableName="satya" value="#[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[1]/Sender')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

and then I did this

```
 #[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[Sender="flowVars.satya"]/Receiver')]
```

There is no value being extracted. But when I used the below logic it worked

```
 #[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[Sender="Satya"]/Receiver')]
```

My flow configuration is as follows

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="Sender_TransformationFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Satyakeerthika_Ch\Desktop\Input" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <set-variable variableName="satya" value="#[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[1]/Sender')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-variable variableName="xpath" value="#[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[Sender= &quot;+ flowVars.satya +&quot;]/Receiver')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.xpath]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.satya]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I want to know how I can use the flowVars instead of a hard coded value in the Xpath to do check.
I am using Anypoint Studio version 5.1.0

Comment: You are missing the single quotes either side of the &quot; Use the expression I posted as is:#[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[Sender=' &quot;+ flowVars.satya +'&quot;]/Receiver')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing flow vars from xpath3 function you should use **'$'** without 'flowVars'

Take a look to the documentation

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath#query-parameters

In your example:

```
<set-variable variableName="xpath" value="#[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[Sender=$satya]/Receiver')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String concatenation to build up the expression, this will work:

```
 #[xpath3('/DatabaseValues/Value[Sender=&quot;' + flowVars.satya + '&quot;]/Receiver')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Tried it. But did not work. It is not extracting any value.

Comment: That works for me based on the xml you posted. Can you post the full config you are using now? make sure to use &quot; and not '